# Tracking specific accounts on twitter using Stream api

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to track specific accounts on twitter by using the stream api. I see understand how to filter the stream by specific words, but I don't understand how to filter by specific accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `follow` keyword in your request as stated in [the docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#follow). You need to pass:

> A comma-separated list of user IDs, indicating the users whose Tweets should be delivered on the stream.